# Flash redirect SWF file

Tags: html, flash

Is there a way to get click event then redirect on swf embedded object?

Below is the code I have at the moment but it doesn't seem to be working

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="560" height="80" id="ad_cat" align="">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://roadsonline.com.au/assets/ads/COA0460_560x80.swf?clickTAG=catredir.php">
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> 
                    <embed src="http://roadsonline.com.au/assets/ads/COA0460_560x80.swf?clickTAG=catredir.php" quality="high" width="560" height="80" name="movie"  wmode="transparent" align=""  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" plugins page="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 
                </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts, HTML and the clickTAG in the SWF.

I believe your html should work - although i recommend a hardlink like http://yoursite.com/redirect.php. So lets talk Flash shall we?

I wrote a tutorial for click tags for my employees a while back which explains what you need to do in flash. This is AS2:

http://ryanhollingsworth.com/index.php/banner-ad-tutorials/item/34-actionscript-20-basic-clicktag-and-fundamentals

AS3 ClickTAG:

```
  import flash.display.MovieClip;

    var hit = new MovieClip();
    hit.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    hit.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
    var clicky = new SimpleButton(null,null,null,hit);
    this.addChild(clicky);

     clicky.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e){
 if(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG) navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank");
 e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

further reading:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html